# Device lookup failed cryptswap1. Can't boot after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, server, bootloader, boot-repair

After i upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 yo Ubuntu 18.04 i'm getting an error:

[image]

After running the command suggested below the error message this appears
[image]

It says: "Failed to activate with key file '/dev/urandom': Device or resource busy.
Loading cryptographic parameters failed: invalid argument.
Failed to activate: Invalid argument.

Some more details:
[image]

Comment: can you use GRUB to boot into recovery (with networking)?  Then you can run the command `systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service` as advised by the error.  This should hopefully provide more insight into the problem.

Comment: Please change (ie. edit your question) to reflect 16.04 to 18.04 :)   If you have encrypted home (which was common before 18.04), it was depreciated as the default, being replaced with full disk encryption (excluding boot, or including boot) as the default, and a package needed to be added on prior systems before it worked normally (I had the same issue long ago; I forget what the package was; is `ecryptfs-utils` installed?)

Comment: It says i do have ecryptfs-utils version 111-0ubuntu5

Comment: @Nmath guiverc I'm now in a computer (was on a phone) Just added a better quality screenshot and wrote the error that appears.

Comment: @guiverc I did and also added a new screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I did was commenting out the line contained in /etc/crypttab after that the system started working. What I don't know now is if I still have a swap drive or not. Actually, I'm not sure if this was the correct solution. But, at least, I can login now and all works.

Comment: Well done on solving it !!!   If you enter `free -h`  (*the -h for human digits; I hate big numbers*), so you see any numbers on the *swap* line?  I can't confirm it's correct (busy), but if the issue is only swap partitions, I'd just re-create or re-set them up again.

Comment: It says:      Swap:          3.2G        825M        2.4G

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, swap is working but not encrypted? Is just that? I don't actually need it encrypted...

Comment: I can only read the first image you provided and don't have time to explore the issue.. You asked if you "*still have a swap drive or not*" in your answer which was what I was responding to. I'd look in your /etc/fstab (file system table) to see how it's used, or ask a another question about swap given this question was about booting & is now answered.